# Placing toolbar into Windows taskbar (ala language bar)

Tags: windows, winapi, taskbar

I'm currently in the process of writing a Windows MFC app to quickly search our corporate DMS. The idea is to have a button placed at the right hand edge of the windows taskbar much like the language bar, that when clicked, would popup the search interface.

I can't seem to find much regarding how placing items in the taskbar like this is performed, can anyone point me to some useful resources or examples?

I'd prefer native API resources (that is, not .NET) if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347274/how-can-i-programatically-tell-windows-taskbar-to-open-or-close-a-given-toolbar

Answer (score 7):

Such toolbar is named a Deskband.
Here's an example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the [StExBar](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/StExBar). It implements an explorer toolbar which can also be added to the taskbar. Doesn't use MFC though, just plain win32.