# Display a complete application in Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: winapi, windows-7, taskbar, windows-shell

On Windows 7, is it possible to create an application to be displayed in the taskbar? What I have in mind is a small widget like a media player or a weather widget, etc.

Something like the mockup below:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Placing toolbar into Windows taskbar (ala language bar)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784231/placing-toolbar-into-windows-taskbar-ala-language-bar) even though this seems to be a better question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's possible. What you are looking for is a toolbar or sometimes referred to as "desk band":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099.aspx#desk_bands